# React/Express set-cookie not working across different subdomains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, authorization

I have a React frontend with Express API server, and I am trying to store a JWT in a secure httpOnly cookie for authorization. Below are the relevant parts of my code, which includes everything I've tried from countless Google/StackOverflow searches.

Am I missing something simple? I am trying to avoid storing the JWT in `localStorage`, but I am just at a loss right now. Nothing seems to work.

**API** (https://api.mydomain.com):

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['SET-COOKIE'],
  origin: 'https://staging.mydomain.com',
}));

app.post('/auth/login', (request, response) => {
  ...

  response.cookie('jwt', JWT.sign({ id: user.id }, ...), {
    domain: 'mydomain.com',
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
  });

  response.json(user);
});
```

**Web** (https://staging.mydomain.com):

```
await fetch('https://api.mydomain.com/auth/login', {
  body: JSON.stringify({ ... }),
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: 'POST',
});
```

I see the `set-cookie` header in the response, but I do not see the cookie set in the developer tools and it is not passed in subsequent API requests.

```
Response Headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://staging.mydomain.com
access-control-expose-headers: SET-COOKIE
set-cookie: jwt=abcde*********.abcde*********.abcde*********; Domain=mydomain.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server, when you are setting the cookie, can you try adding a dot before the domain. The leading dot implies that the cookie is valid for subdomains as well.

```js
response.cookie('jwt', JWT.sign({ id: user.id }, ...), {
  domain: '.mydomain.com',
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: true,
});
```

When the client (here, https://staging.mydomain.com) will receive the `Set-Cookie` response header, with the trailing dot domain, it would accept the cookie since now the cookie is valid for subdomains too.

On a side note, I find [Cookie Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-editor/hlkenndednhfkekhgcdicdfddnkalmdm?hl=en) really helpful for debugging cookies.

Hope this answer helps you! :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried this and, unfortunately, see no change. :(

Comment: Oof, nvm that did work. Ironically, I made a typo in my original post that ended up being right. I have credentials inside of headers in my fetch call, but when I typed out the pseudo-code in my post, I put it outside of headers (which ended up being the right way). The cookie is being set correctly now and sent on subsequent requests. Thanks so much!