# How to store a cookie sent from Express server by using fetch API in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, fetch-api

I'm trying to create signup  Form using `React`, `Express` and `MongoDB`. I successfully implemented the post request and saved the `user` data in the database.

However,though the `user` is saved in the database, I failed to store ( see it the browser ) the `jwt` token using `res.cookie('jwt',token)`.

I have a simple `form` made in **React**:

```js
type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};
export const SignupLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const user = {
        email: 'alexy@gmail.com',
        username: 'alexladies',
        password: 'pasrfsfsdfgfdsd',
        securityQuestion: "father's name",
        securityAnswer: 'jhon',
        joinedDate: '12-12-2023',
    };
     

    const handleSignup = async (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // The problem is here
        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
            .then((reponse) => reponse.json())
            .then((json) => console.log(json))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSignup}
            method='post'
            action='/signup'
            className='sm:px-20 md:w-2/3 md:px-12 lg:w-1/2 lg:px-4 lg:my-4 xl:mt-16 xl:w-1/3 xl:px-16 mx-auto bg-white rounded-2xl py-10 text-center  '
        >
            {children}
        </form>
    );
};
```

My express server:

```js
const User = require('../../models/user');
const { handleError } = require('./error');
const { createToken } = require('../utils/token');

const getSignup = (req, res) => {
    // It stores the cookie in the browser succesfully
    res.cookie('name', 'value');
    res.send('ok');
};

const postSignup = async (req, res) => {
    // It failed to store the cookie in the browser !
    const {
        email,
        password,
        username,
        securityQuestion,
        securityAnswer,
        joinedDate,
    } = req.body;

    const user = new User({
        email,
        password,
        username,
        securityQuestion,
        securityAnswer,
        joinedDate,
    });

    await user
        .save()
        .then(() => res.cookie('jwt', createToken(user._id)))
        .then(() => res.status(200).json(user._id))
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(400).json(handleError(err));
        });
};

module.exports = { getSignup, postSignup };
```

I have tried to add:

```js
 credentials:'include'
```

But it does not work.

#### Sreenshot

[image]

Comment: What is `createToken` doing?

Comment: It generates `jwt` token.

Comment: Maybe show code?

Comment: Maybe helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458456/react-express-set-cookie-not-working-across-different-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging, I found the issue was in the server `cors` options.

Because I have different origins:

1. Client: `http://localhost:5173/`
2. Server: `http://localhost:3000`

It must configure `cors` in the server before sending responses to the client.

The configuration should be like this :

```js
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
        exposedHeaders: ['SET-COOKIE'],
    })
);
```

It allows the server to expose the cookie in the **Header** response and send it back to the **browser** when it receives a request from the **client** ( React ).

In our **client** ( React ) we have to set `credentials:'important` :

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
            credentials: 'include', // Important
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        });
```

It allows it to **set the cookie** sent back in cross-origin requests.